# ToString() - Localize float without adding unnecessary trailing zeroes?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been having some issues with localizing numbers using the method ToString():

`ToString("Nx")` localizes all the thousands separators properly, but adds unnecessary trailing 0s to *whole numbers* that look pretty ugly in my UI. On the other hand, stuff like `ToString("0.###")` handles the decimals JUST how I want it, but it doesn't properly include the thousands separator.

I would like the string to keep as many decimals as I want, but not add trailing 0s to fill in the blanks.

```
float a = 1900.42f;

//Expected result: 1,900.42
a.ToString("N2"); //1,900.42 (Perfect!)
a.ToString("0.##"); //1900.42 (Missing separators)

float b = 1900;

//Expected result: 1,900
b.ToString("N2"); //1,900.00 (Localized, unnecessary 0s)
b.ToString("0.##"); //1900 (Missing separators, no 0s)
```

**Is there any way to have both?** At the moment I'm getting by with adding:

```cs
.Trim('0').Trim(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0])
```

but this feels excessive and unnecessary, and I'm having to assume the decimal separator is just one character. Feels like there should be a way to do what I want already made, I just can't find it.

Comment: I think what you're getting at is that specifying just `N` instead of `N2` uses the _default number of decimal places_,  (which happens to be 2 in my locale) and you're looking for a way to get _group separators_ but not _fixed precision_.  Is that right?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the same functionality as `0.##` where it keeps the decimals but doesn't pad them to fill up to a specific amount, while also keeping the thousands separator localized like `Nx`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include group (thousands) separators in the output, your format string just needs a comma (`,`) between any two digit placeholders (`#` or `0`). For the two specific examples you gave, the format string `"#,0.##"` produces the desired results:

```
float a = 1900.42f;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("#,0.##")); // 1,900.42 for the en-US culture
float b = 1900;
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("#,0.##")); // 1,900
```

If you don't want to hardcode the number of decimal places, you can instead use the default number of decimal places specified by the current culture:

```
string format = $"#,0.{new string('#', NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalDigits)}";
float a = 1900.42f;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString(format)); // 1,900.42
float b = 1900;
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString(format)); // 1,900
```

Caution: The format string `"#,#.##"` (Wyck's answer) produces `""` (an empty string) instead of `"0"` for zero.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `#,#.##`.

Use `,` for culture-specific group separators, `.` for culture-specific decimal separators, and `.##` to get at most 2 digits after the decimal separator. (which is different from `.00`, which would "zero-fill", which is *not* what you wanted. Whereas `#` only prints digits if needed.)

Building on @alelom's answer:

```
double source = 1000000.123;
Console.WriteLine(source.ToString("#,#.##", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de")));
source = 1000000;
Console.WriteLine(source.ToString("#,#.##", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de")));
```

output:

```
1.000.000,12
1.000.000
```

Please refer to the documentation for [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Answer (score 0):

The method `ToString()` with `CultureInfo`:

```cs
double source = 1000000.987654321;
source.ToString("n", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de")).Dump();
```

returns the following:

```
1.000.000,988
```

Which has the same number of significant fractional digits as `ToString("0.###")`, and the thousands separator appropriate for the culture of choice (`de` in this example).

Comment: your code may produce a string with trailing zeros for whole numbers(without decmial points).

Comment: I think this has the same problem.  if you change `source = 1000000` then the output is `1.000.000,000` which is undesired because of the trailing `0`'s after the decimal separator which happens to be a `,` in _de_ locale.

Comment: Thanks, at the moment of answering OP's question still wasn't clear enough to mention that this is what they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I used a conditional statement to check if the formatted number contains the decimal separator. If it does, it trims trailing zeros and the decimal separator. If not, it only trims the decimal separator.

```
using System.Globalization;

double number = 10003420.9987654321;

string formattedNumber = number.ToString("N3", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

formattedNumber = formattedNumber.Contains(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)
    ? formattedNumber.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0])
    : formattedNumber.TrimEnd(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]);

Console.WriteLine(formattedNumber);
```

---

Output

> 10,003,420.999